# Define a timer in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

I have a function in JavaScript. I use `setInterval` in order to control my function. I also have another logic for controlling my function. I have a counter which is increased once one condition happens and is decreased when another condition happens. Now, sometimes the second condition does not happen and hence my function won't be resume anymore. (I pause my function when my first condition happen). Therefore, I want to wait at most 30 seconds for the second condition. If it does not happen, then I want to resume my function anyway. I have following code, but it does not work as I expect it. What happens is that it resume my function every 30 seconds. Then, it may be resumed while it should wait. Can someone let me know what is the problem with my code?

Please note that, the value for the counter may increase to more than 20. I mean the first and second condition may occur more than once.

```
function main() 
{
    // body
}

function increaseCounter()
{
    counter += 1;

    clearInterval(controller);
    controlSecond = setInterval(function(){
        counterSeconds += 1;
        if (counterSeconds == 30)
        {
            counterSeconds = 0;

            controller = setInterval(main, 100);
            clearInterval(controlSecond);
        }
    }, 1000);
}

function decreaseCounter()
{
    counter -= 1;

    if (counter == 0)
    {
        counterSeconds = 0;
        clearInterval(controlSecond);

        controller = setInterval(main, 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: How are these 2 functions called? Can you put up a simple demo via jsfiddle?

Comment: To be honest it's a bit difficult since this is a small part of my big project! In fact I use PhantomJS and these two functions are two of its callbacks functions.

Comment: You have to put  `clearInterval(x);` right before every `x = setInterval(...)` statement.

Comment: Thank you! this solved most of my problems. `clearInterval` right before setting that.

Answer (score 2):

Consider what happens if you call `increaseCounter` twice in a row.

On the first execution it will create **interval A** and assign it to `controlSecond`.

On the second execution it will create **interval B** and assign it to `controlSecond`, while **interval A** continues to fire off indefinitely.  You won't stop it with `clearInterval(controlSecond)` because `controlSecond` no longer references **interval A**.

The problem is that you continue to set `controlSecond` and `controller` to a new interval without clearing them first.  That results in the intervals being leaked with no way of clearing them.  It's sort of like a memory leak where you have dynamically allocated memory but nothing pointed at it, but instead of renegade memory you have renegade intervals.

One way to prevent this is to make sure you always clear your interval before setting it.

I would also recommend that you implement `controlSecond` with a `setTimeout` because that is designed for tasks which only happen once.

Comment: I understand your point which is correct! But, I don't want to use `setTimeout` because I want my functions to be resumed at the time they are ready. But, using `setTimeout` I have to wait for example for 3 seconds each time. That would be too much for some of actions and maybe less for some others. How can I `clear` my `interval` before setting them again?

Answer (score 0):

Why not

```
var counter = 0
var timeout = null

function main () {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = null;
}

function increaseCounter () {
    counter++;
    if (!timeout)
        timeout = setTimeout(main, 30*1000);
}

function decreaseCounter() {
    counter--;
    if (counter === 0) 
        main();
}
```